# Как создать изолированный HttpListener

Tags: c#

Есть 10 ПК, которые подключаются к терминальной ферме. Хочу в каждой сессии запускать `HttpListener` с одним и тем же портом, но чтобы они были изолированны друг от друга.

На данный момент, если я попытаюсь запустить данный код на двух ПК одновременно выдаст ошибку что порт занят. Можно ли как то изолированно запустить этот процесс?

```
   HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8888/");
    listener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Ожидание подключений...");
    HttpListenerContext context = await listener.GetContextAsync();
    // остальное содержимое
    listener.Stop();
```

Comment: почему не использовать другой порт?

Comment: ну, допустим, 10 юзеров запустили 10 таких программ, и тут 11й юзер зашел и открыл браузер на http://localhost:8888/, что он увидеть должен? Какая из запущенных программ обработает запрос?

Comment: Порты располагаются вне процессов, и позволяют осуществлять *кросспроцессорное взаимодействие* по-определению. Прямого пути нету. Есть "обходной". Т.е. нужно получить таблицу `netstat -all` (поля ADDR PORT PID) по ней, найти какому процессу принадлежит ответный сокет, и... допустим по pipe каналу (или другим способом, способ уточнить) отфутболить пакет процессу с преобразованым PID (нужно ещё проверить существует ли процесс в сессии с полученым PID), ждать ответ, и забрать ответ назад. Если пакет не футболится-значит приложение там не запущено. Т.е. AsvSocket -> PID -> SessionID -> listenPID

Comment: Т.е. ваш вопрос делится на 4 вопроса или более. 1) Получить таблицу сокетов `netstat -all` найти в ней PID. 2)Как из PID узнать SessionID 3)Сосставить пары SessionID и listenPID 4)Как пробросить пакет с Socket в listenPID одним из кросспроцессных методов (например pipe). Дать ответ - ответ очень обширный и займет уйму времени.

Comment: Если задача не такая важная - то можете просто в случае "ошибки", увеличивать порт на еденицу, и делать повторно listen.